# countdown oder sleep function in google script spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

At first i want to say sorry for my bad english...
Since 7 days i try to program with google script.
What i want:
After 5 min (for example) thecolums/rows A1:B4 (for example) should be erased.
I want to solve that with der sleep function, but it doesen't works.
i also doesen't work with a thread. 
Mybe some of this forum can help me :-)

```js
function test(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var i=0;
  for(i; i<10; i++){
   if (i=10){
    ss.getRange(3,4,9,1).setValue("");
     }
    else{
  Utilities.sleep(5000);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't "sleep" take seconds as its argument?  5000 seconds is about an hour and a half.

Comment: that was ony an example...
the function don't wait any time.

Comment: Maybe try erasing when i=9 instead of when i=10.  Or run the "for" loop for (i; i<=10; i++)

Comment: The documentation for sleep states that the time is specified in milliseconds, and that 5 minutes is the maximum sleep time.  300000 milliseconds is the maximum sleep time.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a time-based trigger?

[image: Time Trigger]

In the Apps Script code editor, use the **Resources** menu

Unless you only want that code to run once after five minutes?

You can manage a trigger programmatically:

[Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically)

So, you could set a trigger in code to run at a specific time.

[Trigger Builder - Run after a certain amount of time](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#after(Integer))

```
// Creates a trigger that will run 10 minutes later
 ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
   .timeBased()
   .after(10 * 60 * 1000)
   .create();
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things to note :

1. the EQUAL condition in JavaScript is `==` and not a single `=`
   ,  so you condition is not working.
2. Glenn Randers-Pehrson is right in his comment, the condition i==10 will never be true since you count from 0 to 9.

if you rewrite this code correctly it will work as expected.

see code below :

```
function test(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
   if (i==9){
    ss.getRange(3,4,9,1).setValue("");
     }
    else{
  Utilities.sleep(5000);// argument is in millisecs > total time here is 45 seconds (9*5)
      }
    }
}
```

This code can also be written more simply :

```
function test(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
    Utilities.sleep(5000);
     }
    ss.getRange(3,4,9,1).setValue("");
}
```

Note that Sandy's solution in the other answer is also a possible way to do it...

Comment: Thank you for alle posts!!! It works wunderfull :-)
Gives in the class range a method that i can "block" a range/area in the sheet and a method to unblock the same area again??

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer. Could you clarify your question in a new post please?  Danke :-)